# Magento 2 add custom link to username dropdown

Tags: magento-2.1, module, custom

[image]

can anyone tell me how to create a custom link ("MY VEHICLE") in the dropdown from username of a logged in user. I am a beginner and have no idea where to start, any help is greatly appretiated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it to work another way, its similar to the codes @Zefiryn gave.

> **Link.php**

```
namespace [vendor]\[module]\Block;
class Link extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link
{
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

/**
 * Render block HTML.
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function _toHtml() {
    return '<li><a'.$this->getLinkAttributes().'>'.$this->escapeHtml($this->getLabel()).'</a></li>';
    }
}
```

> default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="top.links">
        <block class="[vendor]\[module]\Block\Link" name="test-top-link" before="my-account-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Something</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Find a block that renders those elements and try this

```
<referenceContainer name="block-name">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="home" after="-">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">custom-link-class</argument>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="helper" helper="Vendor\Module\Helper\Menu::getVehicleLinkLabel></argument>
            <argument name="path" xsi:type="helper" helper="Vendor\Module\Helper\Menu::getVehicleLinkUrl"/>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

then create helper class like

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;

class Menu extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $customerSession;

    public function __construct(Context $context, Session $customerSession)
    {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getVehicleLinkLabel()
    {
        return $this->customerSession->isLoggedIn() ? __("My Vehicle (%1)", $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getName()) : null;
    }

    public function getVehicleLinkUrl()
    {
        return $this->_urlBuilder->getUrl('link/to/page');
    }
}
```

Remember that block may be cached by full page cache and block_html so this customer dependent link might require some tweaking to generate correctly for each customer.

Comment: is there something i need to add along with these, i just tried adding to magento-customer core module (not the best practice, just wanted to see if it will work, and its just a local machine) nothing happened, i didn't change the code in anyway(except for a quote that you seem to be missing), can you tell me if i am doing something wrong?

Comment: What exactly you've added and to which class?

Comment: i added the xml part to customer_account_index.xml layout page and created a helper Menu.php

Comment: [Link](http://pastebin.com/67rV0Qrn) to customer_account_index.xml, in case you want to see what i did

Comment: You are missing one `</block>`, check http://pastebin.com/Hv7taV3e

Comment: tried that , still not working

Comment: Are you sure you are adding this link to the correct block? Right now it is added to page.main.title.

Comment: i am not sure, i am a beginner, and probably might be doing something wrong,i know its annoying, but could you give me step by step instruction.

Comment: You have it. Find out what is the block name that renders those links by analyzing xmls in magento modules and your theme. Then use this name in the xml you've already tried. After that clear all cache and check if it's working.

Comment: thankyou , your code really helped me